# ActiveMQ persistence store for large message size

Tags: activemq-classic, leveldb

IF producer is sending message of large message size (let's say 120 MB). How does kahadb and levelDB handle such messages.

kahadb: What I understand is journal size is 32 MB by default. and If i send message more than 32MB, how it will handle such message ? Do I need to change this size to appropriate value according to message size?

leveldb: By default 100mB is default size to store message data. After which rolling happens. IF message is more than 100mB. How does it handle ?

Thanks,
ANuj

Answer (score 0):

For Kahadb we have rolling log of messages, messages and commands are stored in data file of fixed length,if the length exceeds the size of message journal then new file is created.
KahaDB just appends the new message to existing journal and takes care of creating new journal.

Also,KahaDB holds indexes to messages in form a BTree.These Btree indexes hold references to the messages in data logs indexed by their message ID.In short KahaDB will know exactly where your message is stored with the help of this index.So, adding any new configuration for storing this message should not be required

Regarding the whole message in single data log file, I am not sure may be bit research needed
and before trying your luck at changing the journalSizeLength for KahaDB please got through this 
[link](http://blog.garytully.com/2011/11/activemq-multiple-kahadb-instances.html) (reading comments there might be helpful)

Good luck!

Hope it helps.

Comment: When I tested I see that it does not roll the logs for same messages. Instead, it keep the size flexible, if I send a mesage of 200MB , kahadb will create journal of 200MB. So it looks like kahadb has to keep one messages within the same file even if it crosses the limit on journal size. I have seen same behavior for levelDB. Correct me if I am wrong about this.